# lines are not intersecting in perfect fashion

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Am trying to draw exactly like the left picture.
All the lines have same gap and they are rotated in same positive and negative angle.
But no way i can make them intersect perfectly.
They create gaps.... circled it.
Why?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The lines must have equal spacing AND the rotation angle must be selected properly. Try plus and minus 60 degrees. It generates a pattern which is known as "isometric grid". The next image is from Inkscape, but it doesn't affect geometry which was known at least 2500 years ago.

[image]

Comment: i knew angles matter here... but could not identify it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I would construct things differently.

- Draw a Square
- Use `Object > path > Split Into Grid` to define the same amount of rows and columns
- Rotate 45°
- Draw the verticals
- If you want less square sections, use the Free Transform tool to "squish" things vertically a bit.

... here's a quick and dirty animation of the above steps...

[image]

You can actually create the verticals quickly by drawing the first, middle and last vertical, select all three lines, and use `Object > Blend > Make` Then `Object Blend > Blend Options` to adjust the settings.

[image]

Then expand the blend if you need individual lines.

Comment: excellent. thank you.